# NLog how to access RequestId?

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I want to save `Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` into database, because that is Request Id which user see in default error view. But how ? **HttpContext** is not available in startup.cs and i tried access HttpContext in **LayoutRenderer** not successfully.

**Error method in HomeController**

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var model = new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier };

    return View(model);
}
```

I tried LayoutRenderer

```
namespace Copacking.Web.Utils
{
    [LayoutRenderer("requestid")]
    public class NLogRequestIdLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
    {
        protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            builder.Append(Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting an error with **HttpContext**, because object reference is required.

How can i solve it ? In **Nlog.config** file **${aspnet-traceidentifier}** is working but **${activityid}** variable is empty :/

Comment: Try injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not directly familiar with NLog, so forgive me if I'm missing something here, but in a truly abstracted logging setup, you shouldn't really have any hard NLog depedency, anyhow. Ideally, you should be using something like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and simply plugging NLog into that as the provider.

Then, from the controller perspective, you simply inject your logger, and log directly there:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public ErrorController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }

    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger(feature.Error.TargetSite.DeclaringType);
        logger.LogError(feature.Error, "{RequestId} {ErrorMessage}", new
        {
            RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier,
            ErrorMessage = feature.Error.Message
         });

         var model = new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier };

         return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You are completely right I am just thinking about two approaches. One is log only unhandled exceptions in Error method in HomeController (All exceptions are redirected there) If I use Nlog directly i can setup additional variables. But if I register Nlog as Ilogger provider now i dont need call log insertion because it is called automatic in the case of unhandled error. But in the automatic way (NLog as a provider) I dont know how to setup RequestId. I will try the IHttpContextAccessor way into LayoutRenderer or after that i will try different log provider.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following with https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore:

```
layout="${activityid:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}}"
```

Remember to include the following in NLog.config:

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

Comment: This seems nice because it doesn't require adding extra code!

Comment: If you are on 3.X you will need  4.9.1 or higher to get the correct id
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/

Answer (score 4):

> How can i solve it ? In Nlog.config file ${aspnet-traceidentifier} is working but ${activityid} variable is empty :/

As per [NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer) `${Activity}` takes the value from `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId`. You try assigning a value at the request start.

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.Equals(Guid.Empty))
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Thank you, this could work, but i already switched to Serilog.